# Alternative Ways to change image color on hover (filters not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on this site `http://66.147.244.95/~crossfy6/`  and I found some [open source code](http://cssdeck.com/labs/iconic-buttons) for animated icons in circles and revised it for my main menu icons.

Unfortunately, it wasn't until after making it in chrome (if you view it in chrome it works perfectly) I did test it in another browsers and found out that the greyscale filter I used isn't supported in IE and Safari.

I'm wondering if there are any other ways I can accomplish this effect. I thought of creating another set of icon pictures that were grey and transitions them on hover, but the only way to do that would be to rewrite the bulk of the menu since there all set as img's and not backgrounds to divs that I can change with css. Any other thoughts? Or do I basically need to start over? I know the basics of jquery and javascript but not how to implement them with wordpress, which is what I'm using.

HTML

```
<div class="gridcontainer clearfix">
<div class="grid_3">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
        <a href="http://66.147.244.95/~crossfy6/about/">
            <div class="fmcircle_border">
                <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_red">
                    <span  style="width:110px;" >ABOUT</span><img src="http://66.147.244.95/~crossfy6/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/red-question-mark-e1394408760835.png" style="padding-right:5px; width:63px;"  alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="grid_3">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
        <a href="http://66.147.244.95/~crossfy6/wod/">
            <div class="fmcircle_border">
                <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_red">
                    <span style="width:128px;">WOD</span><img src="http://66.147.244.95/~crossfy6/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/red-kettlebell-icon.png" style="width:80px" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="grid_3">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
        <a href="http://66.147.244.95/~crossfy6/nutrition/">
            <div class="fmcircle_border">
                <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_red">
                    <span style="width:124px;">NUTRITION</span><img src="http://66.147.244.95/~crossfy6/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/apple.png" style="width:80px" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="grid_3">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
        <a href="http://66.147.244.95/~crossfy6/rates-and-fees/">
            <div class="fmcircle_border">
                <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_red">
        <span>RATES</span><img src="http://66.147.244.95/~crossfy6/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/red-wallet.png" style="margin-top:27px" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="grid_3">
    <div class="fmcircle_out">
        <a href="http://66.147.244.95/~crossfy6/schedule/">
            <div class="fmcircle_border">
                <div class="fmcircle_in fmcircle_red">
                    <span style="padding-left: 5px;">SCHEDULE</span><img src="http://66.147.244.95/~crossfy6/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/red-calendar.png" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* -- Circular Work -- */
.gridcontainer {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.grid_3 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    width: 170px;
}

.grid_9 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 700px;
}

.fmcircle_out {
    width: 138px;
    height: 138px;
    background-color:#dd2027;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    opacity: 1; 


    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -o-border-radius: 100px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.fmcircle_out:hover {
    opacity: 1; 


    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

/*
.fmcircle_out:hover .fmcircle_in img {
    margin: 20px;
    width: autopx;
    height: 90px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
*/

.fmcircle_in {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);

    border-radius: 85px;
    -moz-border-radius: 85px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 85px;
    -o-border-radius: 85px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.fmcircle_out:hover .fmcircle_in {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);  
    border-radius: 85px;
    -moz-border-radius: 85px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 85px;
    -o-border-radius: 85px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.fmcircle_in img {
    border: none;
    margin: 23px;
    width: auto;
    height: 85px;


    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.fmcircle_in span {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    width: 120px;
    background: none;
    color: #000;
    font-size:20px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 52px 0 0 0px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.08em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;

    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -o-border-radius: 2px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.fmcircle_out:hover .fmcircle_in span {
    opacity: 1;



    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

any and all help/insight appreciated! thanks!

Comment: What does the greyscale filter do exactly? I'm on Safari

Comment: It, surprisingly, desaturates the targeted element

Comment: You should be able to get the grayscale filter using svg (see answer) , but  you can also change src in img using css. You need to set content=url(xxx);

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named filters.svg with the following contents:-

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <filter id="grayscale">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
 </filter>
</svg>
```

Add css code

```
.fmcircle_in{
filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}
.fmcircle_out:hover .fmcircle_in {
filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);}
```

add following to css code for IE

```
.fmcircle_in span {filter: alpha(opacity=0);}

.fmcircle_out:hover .fmcircle_in span{filter: alpha(opacity=100);}
```

Comment: thanks so muck for the responses guys! This answer worked for firefox (and I hope therefore safari and opera, I don't have them to test) except that I can't get it to do the half second transition, its just a hard switch from grey to red when you hover. Is that possible or no?

The color change still doesn't work in IE 10, does the svg method not work for it either?